# Excel application thows an exception on setting width

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, comexception

I am trying to control the Excel application via a WPF project.

```
var   xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

xla.Width = 400; // This line is throwing the below exception.
```

It works fine for few times, after few days the same line gives an exception shown below. Logging off and logging on to the system fixes issue temporarily.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.set_Width(Double RHS)
       at EmbedExcel1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Test Projects\EmbedExcel1\EmbedExcel1\Form1.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at EmbedExcel1.Program.Main() in d:\Test Projects\EmbedExcel1\EmbedExcel1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You're saying you use WPF but the stack trace shows a Windows Forms app. What is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Width is not working when Excel window is maximized.

Before setting Width property you should set xla.WindowState = xlNormal

Comment: hi.. 

 ExcelSettings.xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 ws.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true;

when the compiler encounters the above line, it consume lot of time (min 20 sec), to complete that line. 

Even I tried to run these set of line in the Task.Factory.StartNew, but no use..

please help me on this.

Comment: 20 seconds comes from application startup. `ExcelSettings.xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`  means new Excel process is started. This time cannot be shortened. You can optimize later operations i.e. not close Excel between operations etc. What you can do - i.e. start Excel during loading your program to speed up later operations.

Comment: hi.. thanks for the response..
actually,  system is not taking time to create the object, but setting the font bold to true is. 

 ws.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true; // this line..